# How to Change the Position of Manage password window of Browser using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, browser

I have a Login Page. In that Page I have Password Field and for that Password Field I have set the Caps Lock key Indication. when the Caps Lock key is on than the DIV create by me is show below the Password Field as a Tooltip.

[Login Form Caps Lock key On Tooltip Indication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idrry.png)

But My Issue is that when we have saved by the browser than that "Caps Lock Key on" Tooltip DIV is Hiding Behind the manage passwords Bubbles which is display by the Browser.

[Login Form with the manage password Window show by the Browser and the Caps Lock On Indication DIV is hiding behind it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DxpZ.png)

I want the Solution can we handle it with the help of CSS and javascript.  So that when Manage password window will be Detected then the Caps Lock Indicator DIV tooltip Position should change to Left side however the tooltip visible properly.

Please Provide the Solution for Every Browser. mainly for (Google Chrome, Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. )

Comment: Can you try to put the "Caps Lock Key on" tooltip to be show on the top to avoid the overlapping?

Comment: My Requirement is that When the Manage password window will detect only in that case that tooltip shifts to Left side. rest that will show below as behave currently.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using relative positioning in css, i.e.:

```css
#caps-lock-indicator {
   position: relative;
   top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: I want to Handle it Dynamically. When the Manage password window will detect only in that case that tooltip shifts to Left side. rest that will show below the password Field.